# Identify font (Manda Naruto)

Tags: fonts, font-identification, japanese

I would like help identifying the font below (used by Manda in the Naruto manga, chapter #170). I cannot seem to find any font that replicates this one below (having looked through a number of font sites).

[image: text]

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure that this is [イナクズレ](https://archive.sha-ken.co.jp/typeface/209-0-EKZ/), a phototypesetting (filmsetting) font.

A bad news is that, despite its commonness in commercial printing, you are not likely be able to use this font on your computer, as its vendor has been negative to sell their typefaces separately from their machine. A good news is that, this year (2021), they finally announced to move into licensing them for DTP, so hopefully it will be available soon.